# How to get on a minecraft PE server latest

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Please help me I am on the lastest minecraft PE and I need to know how to get on a server ever time I go to external and type in the adresse it just says can't get to world. I do have a minecraft account and loged in

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a Minecraft PE server, or a Minecraft for PC server?

Comment: I am using PE I do need lost oh help

Comment: Yes, but is **the server** you're connecting to a PE server?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you are using the right IP adress and the right Port. If you do that right, make sure that the server you are using is online. If that is all right and it still does not load, try tapping the server multiple times. Sometimes it doesn't work the first time. If it still does not work, make sure your Wifi is in and you are signed into your Minecraft account. If all this is right and it still doesn't work, I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you but a heard you had to be invited thank you for the help anyway